# solve linear programming by simplex on MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have `A`, `b`, `f` matrices as follows :

```
A = [ 2 1 
      1 2 ]

B = [ 4; 3 ]

F = [ 1; 1 ] 

LB = [ 0; 0 ]

[X, fval, exitflag, output, lambda] = linprog(F, A, B, [], [], LB)
```

After that, the solution provided by the MATLAB is surprising. It says the value of `fval` is `1.2169e-013`. This is not the solution. Can you help me by identifying the fault?

Comment: Can you write (with formula) what problem you wish to solve please?

Comment: The optimization value of this problem is 7/3 . So the solution is wring

Comment: Ok, I write the formula for you ... The solution is indeed 0 for your problem here: as you have written the problem, you want to solve `min(x+y)` subject to `2*x+y<4 , x+2*y<3 , x>0 and y>0`. The best solution is (0,0) for sure. Don't you have missed any sign?

Comment: I want to maximizE the function .

Comment: So take `-F` instead of F; the optimization value will be `-2.3333`, then take the negative of it to recover the optimization value of your maximization problem. You have to do so as `linprog` solves only minimization problems.

Comment: Many many thanks Bentoy132 . I cant express my gratitude in words .